# Does any budy know how to reproduce this hover effect on this page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to reproduce the  effect that you get when you go over the images on this page http://pixabay.com/en/photos/?order=best

if you go over with the mouse there appearce a window with borders with a bigger picture in it
any hints would be really apreciated!

Comment: Look into the `mouseenter` event.

Comment: the code in question is in `base6.min.js` of the given site if you want to see how they did it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways. But let me inspect how this particular site implements it.

Check the source code of the webpage, for each image, the HTML is like:

```
<div class="item" data-w="270" data-h="180">
  <a href="/en/pine-forest-branch-road-conifer-463469/">
    <img src="/static/uploads/photo/2014/09/27/13/36/pine-463469__180.jpg" class="preview_img" data-url="/static/uploads/photo/2014/09/27/13/36/pine-463469_640.jpg" data-width="492.307692308" data-height="327.692307692" alt="Pine, Forest, Branch, Road, Conifer" title="Pine, Forest, Branch, Road, Conifer">
    <em>Pine, Forest, Branch, Road, Conifer</em>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here you can see, they show the smaller image first, which is `/static/uploads/photo/2014/09/27/13/36/pine-463469__180.jpg`, and the larger image is stored in the `data` attribute of the `<a>` tag, which is `data-url="/static/uploads/photo/2014/09/27/13/36/pine-463469_640.jpg"`. In this way, you can first load the small image to save bandwidth.

Its class `preview_img` is for selecting all preview images. You can see its functionality as follow. The javascript file they are using is `http://pixabay.com/static/js/base6.min.js`, which is a `min` file. But can still search `preview_img` to find the code making effect:

```
var hover_timeout, no_preview=getCookie("no_preview");
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".preview_img", function(e) {
  var o=$(this), i=e.pageX, n=e.pageY;
  if(!no_preview || null != o.data("force-preview")) {
    var r = o.attr("title");
    r && (o.data("title",r), o.attr("title","")), 
      hover_timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        var e=o.data("width"), 
            r=o.data("height"), a=r, 
            s=o.data("cut"), 
            c=o.data("title");
        if(s&&(a+=s),!(e+30>ww||r+30>wh||e+30>wh||r+30>ww)) {
           preview = $('<div class="open_preview_img" style="z-index:'+(max_zindex+10)+
                       '"><div style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;width:'+(e+2)+"px;height:"+(r+2)+
                       'px"><img style="width:'+e+"px;height:"+a+'px" src="'+o.attr("src")+'"><img style="width:'+e+'px" src="'+o.data("url")+'"></div>'+(c?"<em>"+c+"</em>":"")+"</div>").prependTo("body");
        ...
```

So you can see that they bind delegate the event `mouseenter` to all images with class `preview_img`. And then populate the HTML code and `.prependTo("body")`. And you can see the `src` attribute of the image is `o.attr("src")`, which is the url of larger image.

Most of the code here is to calculate the position/size information of the large image. Depending on you application, you can customize.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: fancybox

http://fancybox.net/

You need to have knowledge of javascript and jquery.

Answer (score -1):

Here is probably what you need:
http://cssglobe.com/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery/

See "Example 2: Image Preview Gallery" (http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/02/)

You can also search for "thumbnail hover popup".